# Check Open Cursor in Oracle when user doesnot have SYSDBA access

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, cursor

I need to check the open cursor values in Oracle 11g.

I have the queries :

```
select a.value, s.username, s.sid, s.serial# from v$sesstat a, v$statname b, v$session s where a.statistic# = b.statistic#  and s.sid=a.sid and b.name = 'opened cursors current' and s.username is not null;

select  sid ,sql_text, count(*) as "OPEN CURSORS", USER_NAME from v$open_cursor where sid in ($SID);
```

But, all these queries require SYSDBA access for the oracle user. I do not have SYSDBA access on my user id.

Is there any alternate way to do this?
I can use JAVA application or any other application for this.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Those queries do not require `SYSDBA`.  They would require something like the `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY` privilege or the `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE` role or direct grants on the individual tables.  If your DBA will give you one of those things, you can run the queries.  If the DBA objects to giving you access to these objects, you'd need to work with him or her to come up with an acceptable alternative-- for example perhaps the DBA could create a view that runs these queries in a privileged account and grant you access to that view.  It depends on the nature of the DBA's objections.

Comment: Ok. I need to try that. But, I do not think that the DBA will grant me any more privilege. Isn't there any alternate way to find it out?

Comment: If your DBA doesn't want you to be able to query those tables, there is no alternate way to query them, no.  It would be rather insecure of Oracle to provide a lot of back doors for people to be able to query information that the DBA doesn't want to expose.  If you believe you need this information and the DBA believes you shouldn't have access to it, you've got an impasse that someone in your organization needs to resolve.

Comment: Ok. Thanks ... I get your point